# AESManaged Trade Compliance Issue in United States

Tags: encryption, aes

I am currently using AESManaged encryption for my silverlight application. Does AESManaged encryption have a severe trade compliance issue in Bureau of Industry and Security in terms of shipping the application internationally?

Answer (score 2):

I am tempted to say that `AESManaged` is a class provided by the framework, i.e. *you* do not ship it: it is already shipped. Then whatever compliance issue may exist is to be handled (and has been handled) by Microsoft, not you.

(I am not entitled in any way to give legal advice, so do not take my word for it.)

Comment: Whatever compliance issue with AESManaged has been handled by Microsoft. But his code may have its own compliance issues. BIS doesn't care that his code uses AESManaged, they're not interest in the *how*. But if the what is encryption, they are very interested in what it does. (And it goes the other way too. For example, if he has his own AES code, but only uses it to secure licenses, then BIS doesn't care that he has encryption *code* because he doesn't provide an encryption *function*.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - in other words, there might be an issue if somebody would open up a general use encryption function to the user of the application? Can we have a link to the actual text?

Comment: @owlstead what test are you looking for?  The law?  or are you asking if you can provide a link to decrypted text?

Comment: @owlstead If the code provides encryption functions (whether intentionally by design, or 'accidentally' by exposing an API that it only uses for non-encryption purposes but that can be used for encryption purposes), then you have an issue.

Comment: @David, the code provides encryption function. Can you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: If the code provides an encryption function, then you have to comply with the BIS rules.

Answer (score 1):

If your software provides encryption, then you have to go to BIS, even if you're using a third-party framework that was approved by BIS, including Windows APIs.

This is what Apple's Mac App Store requires, even though Mac developers are using Mac OS X built-in encryption approved by BIS; so I trust Apple's lawyers here.